# Can't change touchpad settings since 16.10

Tags: touchpad, alps

I am not really sure if I could edit the touchpad settings in 16.04, but I think so.

Áfter upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10, there is natural scrolling enabled for my touchpad. Still, 2 finger scrolling, tapping... works.

Bit in System settings, I can only adjust the mouse settings.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master                        id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Also, in dconf-editor, I cannot find a touchpad. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
Device Enabled (152):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (287): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (288):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (289):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (290):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (311):  300, 1700, 210, 1190
Synaptics Finger (312): 12, 15, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (313):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (314):   107
Synaptics Tap Durations (315):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (316):   0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (317):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (318):    141
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (319):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (320): 48, 48
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (321): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (322):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (323): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.081934, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (324):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (325):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (326):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (327): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (328):   1, 1, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (329): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (330):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (331): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (332):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (333): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (334):    10, 100
Synaptics Coasting Speed (335): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (336):    15, 80
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (337): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (338):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (339):  0
Synaptics Gestures (340):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (341):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (342): 32, 25
Synaptics Area (343):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (344): 12, 12
Device Product ID (274):    2, 8
Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event8"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput list-props 13` command? You probably are using libinput.

Comment: So I added the requested information. Somehow, "natural scrolling" is not active anymore, still can't access the settings.